# Write a SQL code to select all employees with salary greater than the average department salary and also greater than $30K

Tags: sql

salary(department_id,employee_id,salary)

```
DepartmentID EmployeeID      Salary
    1          1            $30,000.00
    1          2            $25,000.00
    1          3            $40,000.00
    1          4            $33,000.00
    2          5            $25,000.00
    2          6            $50,000.00
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using. If you need a DBMS independent solution, the `sql` tag is enough (although it would help if you explicitly say so)

Comment: sure, thanks for the suggestions ... will do it next time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work

```
select s1.employeeid, s1.departmentid, s1.salary
from salary as s1
  inner join
  (select departmentid, avg(salary) as avgsalary
    from salary 
    group by departmentid) as s2   
  on s1.departmentid = s2.departmentid
where salary > avgsalary and salary > 30000
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT DepartmentID, AVG(salary) AverageSalary FROM Salary
   GROUP BY DepartmentID
)
SELECT s.EmployeeID, s.DepartmentID, s.Salary, c.AverageSalary  
FROM Salary s
INNER JOIN CTE c on c.DepartmentID = s.DepartmentID
WHERE s.salary > c.AverageSalary and s.salary > 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
SELECT t1.DepartmentID,t2.EmployeeID,t2.Salary,t1.average 
FROM
  (SELECT DepartmentID,AVG(Cast(Salary as Float)) as average
  FROM Test
  GROUP BY DepartmentID) t1 
  JOIN Test t2 ON t1.DepartmentID = t2.DepartmentID AND t2.Salary > t1.average AND t2.Salary > 30
```

result : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56426bd1df136124c3923c30e59cf97a)